# AWS Backup Plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Account with a group of instances and I have a Backup plan using AWS Backup with q Backup rule that runs everyday. Total retention period is 3 weeks right now.

Due to high costs I want to change the way I keep the snapshots of the instances. I would like to reduce the costs setting up the retention period to 1 week and I was looking for different ways like using Lambda scripts, S3 storage, Cloud watch or EC2 Lifecycle Manager.

I would like to know what is the most effective way to reduce the cost while having at least 3-4 days backup snapshots ready to go when needed.

I tried to write a lambda script for changing Aws backup snapshots into archive, but they have to be 90 days before deleting. It is cheaper this way, but I think it could be better ways to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.